# C# attributes naming convention

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

Attributes in C# should be named using PascalCase with the 'Attribute' suffix as written [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). My question regards to more subtle thing; how should attributes be named when it comes to natural language?

For instance - I have an authorization attribute in ASP MVC application which checks if logged user is authorized to see a module (represented by particular controller). I've decided to name it as follows:

```
[IsLoggedUserAuthorizedToSeeModule(ModuleName = ModuleManager.Modules.ExampleModule)]
public class ExampleModuleController : BaseController
{
    ...
}
```

It's quite comprehensible to me, but it's a long name, I have doubts about it. Microsoft usually provides short names of default attributes, but they aren't very homogeneous. The `Serializable` attribute means that the decorated class **can be** serialized. The `ObsoleteAttribute` attribute means that decorated class **has** some state. Description and Category attributes define metadata.

Full list of default .NET attributes can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx#inheritanceContinued).

Are there any guidelines about attributes naming convention? Do you know any articles about it?

Comment: `[OnlyVisibleForAuthorized]` would be better in my opinion. It sounds more like a statement, which attributes are about, whereas your name sounds like a function.

Comment: Seems like `ModulePermissions` would be a more general name that could have other attributes added to it later. `IsLoggedUserAuthorizedToSeeModule` is specific and may need to be changed if the attribute needs to support other options in the future.

Comment: Is the user `Logged` to a file or `Logged On` in a session?

Comment: I would name it using an imperative: `[ExposeModuleToAuthenticatedUser]` or `[ExposeModuleToLoggedUser]`

Comment: @MarkJansen Good point, thank you.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Imperative would be nice, but not just authenticated - only authorized.

Comment: Okay, but what about articles or guidelines :)?

Comment: I like the question and enjoyed reading the discussions - but be prepared for this to be closed as "too subjective".  I can see it coming...

Answer (score 2):

Attributes should be named using short and concise pascal-cased sentences.

After all, they decorate assembly members and when you see an applied attribute, you want to understand what do they mean by just reading their name.

Anyway, *how to name your attributes* is subjective. What may be meaningful for me, can be disturbing for you.

About yout concrete attribute `IsLoggedUserAuthorizedToSeeModuleAttribute`, maybe it can be simplified to just `AllowedModuleAttribute` and you should implement another attribute `AuthorizeAttribute` ([or re-use MVC's one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)):

```
// This way you splitted out the concept of "logged users" and "what module"
[Authorize, AllowedModule(ModuleManager.Modules.ExampleModule)]
public class ExampleModuleController : BaseController
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Instead of `AllowedModule`, perhaps just `Module`, because the "Allowed" part is already taken care of by some other attribute (Authorize) in your scenario.

Comment: @SamAxe Well, `Authorize` means *you need to be authorized by security *. This is the reason to maintain `Allowed` as part of the attribute. You can be logged in and authorized, but not allowed to use some module

Comment: I'm afraid you're right it's subjective. When it comes to split of logged users and module I don't need check if user is logged, it's done elsewhere.

Comment: @Landeeyo You don't need to check there "logged users". Attributes are descriptive. Authorize + Allowed module = "You must be logged in and I allow you this module"

Comment: True, but we assume that all controllers are accesses by logged users. We don't allow anonymous (we use windows authentication).

Comment: @Landeeyo At the end of the day, attribute are like `public`, `private`... They're extensions to built-in modifiers. You don't need to think "if I put X attribute, there I should be doing Y". The sum of N attributes mean Z.

Comment: @Landeeyo And again, you're thinking the wrong way... Who cares you assume that all users are already authenticated? In your particular case, this controller wants to express that you need to put these two attributes to define that "authorized users see that module".

Comment: @Landeeyo Your attribute already contains the "Authorize" particle. It's just about splitting out ideas and not making a soup of "all concepts in a single box"

Comment: @Landeeyo Think about data annotations. Do you imagine an attribute "MinLengthAndNotEmptyAttribute"? No. There should be two attributes, MinLength and NotEmpty